# setvisibility in ontouch of a parentviews child

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Problem: 
Only starting from the second time i do the touch movement (physically speaking) 
imageview1 gets visible

Requirement: 
starting from the first time i do the touch movement (physically speaking) 
imageview1 gets visible.  At the end of the touch movement It has to be gone again.  (Initial state)

View hierarchy situation:

Relativelayout:

- FrameLayout (replaced by fragment1)
- imageview1

Fragment1:

- imageview2 (has ontouchlistener)
- imageview3
- imageview4

OnCreateView of the RelativeLayout, imageview1.setvisibility(view.gone)

In ontouchlistener:

```
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        System.out.println("Action Down");
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        System.out.println("Action Up");
        seekArc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        System.out.println("Action down pointer");
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        System.out.println("Move");
        imageview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageview1.measure(imageview1.getWidth(), imageview1.getHeight());
        v.invalidate();
        break;
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance for the aid.

Answer (score 0):

Move `seekArc.setVisibility(View.GONE);` into `case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:`

Comment: Thing is,  I want it to be gone back, after the physical touch event has ended.